# How Can I Pass Variable related to Auth in multiple laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, variables, methods, controller, multiple-views

I have multiple method like below in my laravel controller :

```
public function daily(){
    $sites = Site::all()->where('owner_id', '==', Auth::user()->owner_id);
        return view('backend.daily',compact('sites'));
}
public function weekly(){
    $sites = Site::all()->where('owner_id', '==', Auth::user()->owner_id);
        return view('backend.weekly',compact('sites'));
}
public function yearly(){
    $sites = Site::all()->where('owner_id', '==', Auth::user()->owner_id);
        return view('backend.yearly',compact('sites'));
}
...
```

**I used that in controller constructer :**

```
public function __construct() {
        $sites = Site::all()->where('owner_id', '==', Auth::user()->owner_id);
        View::share('sites', $sites);
}
```

**and use in AppserviceProvider in boot() method , but that doesn't work and get bellow error  :**

```
"Trying to get property 'owner_id' of non-object"
```

**while in normal use it has no error!**

in every method i've used one varible called $sites but it used in multiple views , i want to use $sites once and my code want to be like this shorter :

```
public function daily(){
        return view('backend.daily',compact('sites'));
}
public function weekly(){
        return view('backend.weekly',compact('sites'));
}
public function yearly(){
        return view('backend.yearly',compact('sites'));
}
...
```

**How can i achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
optional(Auth::user())->owner_id
```

If the user is not logged in, you'll probably not be able to get sites from the database.

Comment: sir i don't have problem on authorization , i should use this where ```where('owner_id', '==', Auth::user()->owner_id``` it can not be ignored

Comment: So this should work then: `where('owner_id', '==', optional(Auth::user())->owner_id)`. Did you try it?

Comment: yes this worked but it shows no record ! it look likes that sites variable is not defined when i dd($sites) on blade

Comment: make sure you used `->get()` in the end to `where()`. Like `Site::where('owner_id', '==', Auth::user()->owner_id)->get();`. Try `dd($sites)` in the `AppServiceProvider` to make sure it contains data.

Comment: I've used this code in boot() method in AppServiceProveder and Constructor but it shows nothing and when i use dd($sites) it shows me empty collection ```Collection {#147 ▼
  #items: []
}``` while i have data in normal mode!

Comment: when i use $site variable in for example in yearly() mehod without ```->get()``` that shows me data in Collection